# Why is it a common bug that sites sort states almost-alphabetically in selection menus? (ex. Nevada before New York)

Tags: html

Across the web, a common bug I find is that drop down menus will list "New Hampshire; New Jersey; Nevada; New York".   What can change programmatically that this isn't alphabetized properly?

---

Samples:

**AMCharts (Javascript library for data visualizaition) https://www.amcharts.com/visited_states/**

[image: AMCharts selection checkbox with Nevada before New York]

**Opt Out Pre Screen Website https://www.optoutprescreen.com/form**

[image: www.optoutprescreen.com selection dropdown with Nevada before New York]

**Passport Parking (web page via Google Pay app).**

[image: Passport Parking selection dropdown with Nevada before New York]

Comment: https://www.infoplease.com/us/postal-information/state-abbreviations-and-state-postal-codes Sorted by postal code. Not sure it's much of a programming question though...

Comment: Certainly makes sense, led me to this discussion on English SE https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384812/why-is-nebraska-listed-after-other-states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kaiido seems to have a good guess, these are probably naively sorted by State abbreviations.

Found a similar discussion [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384812/why-is-nebraska-listed-after-other-states), where its suggested that a similar issue may have come from a database that was using the abbreviations as the primary key with no additional sorting.  On closer inspection, the samples have "North Dakoda; Nebraska" also.